# I loaded a program in wine and I cant find it

Tags: 12.04, wine

I am running 12.04 and used wine to install Rosetta stone. It loaded correctly but now I cant find it. It did not create a desktop icon and it doe not show up when i search for it or when I pull up wine and look under the applications tab. I can see it when I go under wine uninstall a program. Any ideas? I would like to create a desktop link Thank you.

Comment: Can you browse for it in the C: drive? Perhaps in program files?

Comment: You should try Play On Linux.

Answer (score 0):

you could try push alt + f2 and type wineremove, and then use wineremove and push tab application, and then add/remove the software from the c: drev /program files, and then delete it this should work, and then install it you can install the software again, and then you can run it from the wine application.